# npm - using stale package data

Tags: npm, npm-install

Whenever I do an npm install, I get a ton of messages about it using stale package data. What does that mean and is it something I need to worry about?

Here's a small example of the warning messages I get with an npm install. In this particular example I just added "npm install @angular/animations@latest --save":

```
WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-Mp+FXEI+FrwY/XYV45b2YD3E8i3HwnEAoFcM0qlZzq/RZ9RwWitt2Y/c7cqRAz70U7hfekqx6qNYthuKFO6K0
g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-Mp+FXEI+FrwY/XYV45b2YD3E8i3HwnEAoFcM0qlZzq/RZ9RwWitt2Y/c7cqRAz70U7hfekqx6qNYthuKFO6K0g== but got sha1-2+xJQ20q4V9TYRTnbRRlbNvA9E0
=. (8538 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-NnSOmMEYtVR2JVMIGTzynRkkaxtiq1xnFBcdQD/DnNCYPoEPsVJhM98BDyaoNOQIi7p4okdi3E27eN7GQbsUu
g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-NnSOmMEYtVR2JVMIGTzynRkkaxtiq1xnFBcdQD/DnNCYPoEPsVJhM98BDyaoNOQIi7p4okdi3E27eN7GQbsUug== but got sha1-wVm41b4PnlpvNG2rlPFs4CIWG4g
=. (3618 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-Mp+FXEI+FrwY/XYV45b2YD3E8i3HwnEAoFcM0qlZzq/RZ9RwWitt2Y/c7cqRAz70U7hfekqx6qNYthuKFO6K0
g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-Mp+FXEI+FrwY/XYV45b2YD3E8i3HwnEAoFcM0qlZzq/RZ9RwWitt2Y/c7cqRAz70U7hfekqx6qNYthuKFO6K0g== but got sha1-2+xJQ20q4V9TYRTnbRRlbNvA9E0
=. (8538 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-NnSOmMEYtVR2JVMIGTzynRkkaxtiq1xnFBcdQD/DnNCYPoEPsVJhM98BDyaoNOQIi7p4okdi3E27eN7GQbsUu
g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-NnSOmMEYtVR2JVMIGTzynRkkaxtiq1xnFBcdQD/DnNCYPoEPsVJhM98BDyaoNOQIi7p4okdi3E27eN7GQbsUug== but got sha1-wVm41b4PnlpvNG2rlPFs4CIWG4g
=. (3618 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
```

Here is the current package.json file that I have for my project:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "me",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css true",
    "build-prod": "ng build -prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "update:packages": "node wipe-dependencies.js && rm -rf node_modules && npm update --save-dev && npm update --save",
    "prestyleguide": "ng build --extract-css true",
    "styleguide": "rimraf dist/styleguide/ && kss --config kss/kss-config.json --custom hidemarkup --custom hideexample --custom hidedefault --custom fakeexample --placeholder .modifier-class",
    "//": "Build just the styleguide without building the entire app (requires that the app has already been built to the dist/ folder)",
    "build-styleguide": "rimraf dist/styleguide/ && kss --config kss/kss-config.json --custom hidemarkup --custom hideexample --custom hidedefault --custom fakeexample --placeholder .modifier-class"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.28",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.15",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "kss": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "random-ext": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.5.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

try that and then reinstall all of your project's dependencies

```
rm ./package-lock.json
rm -r ./node_modules
npm cache clear --force
```

There is a [full thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17146) on github about it, since june I think

Comment: I don't understand how everyone is suggesting removing the package-lock.json is a solution. By doing that you're removing all the guarantees the package-lock.json was put in there for in the first place

Comment: @Rhys does it means that we only need to remove node modules folder and then clear npm cache?

Comment: it should work if your lock is still fine. you just need to try. If it fixes the problem, that's good. if not retry and remove the .lock too

Comment: @Rhys `package-lock.json` gets regenerated during `npm install`.  So in my case, `package-lock.json` got replaced, not removed.  (And that fixed the problem.)

Comment: I'd love an answer to the OP's question: "What does that mean and is it something I need to worry about?" Anyone?

Answer (score 30):

Since npm 5 you don't have full control over the cache, so for npm 5 you could try

```
npm cache verify
```

This helped me. I don't think you have to remove package-lock and node_modules as first step.

Answer (score 4):

#### Should the cache clear method not work...

I found I had this problem during an OS X update. Installing the Command Line Tools update and restarting iTerm fixed this, incredibly enough.

[image: unexpected causes]

Certainly not suggesting this is a "proper" solution but was definitely messing with my setup (wtf apple?). Posted in the event someone else viewing this is in the same position

Comment: I resolved this problem after changing firewall settings. Just adding this for reference if the accepted solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try clearing your NPM cache using:

```
$ npm cache clear --force
```

Then re-install your node modules.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when using a custom registry (not `npmjs.org`). The problem was that my registry had gone down.

Answer (score 2):

Before deleting your `node_modules`, check your internet connection - your provider might do some traffic shaping and blocking or slowing down the access to package repositories. You can spot that if you see something like `Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: [...]` in your error messages.

This was the case for me, and the problem got resolved once I was using VPN.