# I have uninstalled the old cli and now trying to install the new version but is is showing the below error

Tags: angular

I have uninstalled the old cli and trying to install the new cli by npm install -g @angular/cli@1

but I am facing the below error

> `
>   c:\Users\SP00558091\boilerplate\src\app>npm install -g @angular/cli@1
>   npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/:
>   Miscellaneous Warning ECONNREFUSED: request to http://registry.n
>   pmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:4200 npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
>   npm ERR! Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0 while parsing near
>   'Invalid Host header'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\SP00558091\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-16T09_24_00_156Z-debug.log

Comment: check this http://chenmu1.com/blog/how-to-deal-with-npm-warn-registry-unexpected-warning/

Comment: i have used npm cache clear --force    but again the same error appears

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553401/npm-using-stale-package-data try this also

Comment: it is showing this error " 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: have you created new project?

Comment: no, the same project itself, initially ng serve was working fine for me ,later i have uninstalled and trying to install new cli@1.now npm start is working but ng serve is not working

Comment: before npm start try npm install

Comment: npm ERR!   parent: 'shruthi' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SP00558091\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: try to install latest npm

Comment: again the same error

Comment: delete your nodemodules and try npm install

Comment: try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install`

Comment: done still the same error apprears