# Getting Error While creating new Angular App

Tags: angular-cli

I'm getting **Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^5.3.30","chai":"^3.5'** while creating my new Angular Application. I'm not able to figure out why its throwing this exception because my previous Angular Application is working fine. I searched for this error but did not get any solution. Please help me to resolve this error. A big Thank you in advance.

Below are the error I'm getting While creating the new Angular Application.

```
PS D:\Angular> ng new myApppp
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE myApppp/angular.json (3601 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/package.json (1294 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/README.md (1025 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/karma.conf.js (1019 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/index.html (293 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app.component.html (25530 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1101 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app.component.ts (211 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (640 bytes)
CREATE myApppp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^5.3.30","chai":"^3.5'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\amitt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-26T12_43_50_800Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Below are the 2020-01-26T12_43_50_800Z-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--quiet'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose npm-session 8421228fee90bcb7
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall angular-form@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle angular-form@0.0.0~preinstall: angular-form@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 10ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 2ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 2415ms (from cache)
18 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/cli@~8.3.22 fetched in 2430ms
19 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular 2442ms (from cache)
20 silly pacote range manifest for @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.803.22 fetched in 2465ms
21 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 2474ms (from cache)
22 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/compiler-cli@~8.2.14 fetched in 2481ms
23 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core 2583ms (from cache)
24 silly pacote range manifest for jasmine-core@~3.4.0 fetched in 2585ms
25 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode 2868ms (from cache)
26 silly pacote range manifest for @types/node@~8.9.4 fetched in 2880ms
27 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2flanguage-service 2895ms (from cache)
28 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/language-service@~8.2.14 fetched in 2898ms
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-spec-reporter 2918ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote range manifest for jasmine-spec-reporter@~4.2.1 fetched in 2919ms
31 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer 3717ms (from cache)
32 silly pacote range manifest for codelyzer@^5.0.0 fetched in 3718ms
33 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter 1264ms (from cache)
34 silly pacote range manifest for karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@~2.0.1 fetched in 1267ms
35 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher 1303ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote range manifest for karma-chrome-launcher@~2.2.0 fetched in 1305ms
37 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma 1337ms (from cache)
38 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine 1182ms (from cache)
39 silly pacote range manifest for karma@~4.1.0 fetched in 1346ms
40 silly pacote range manifest for karma-jasmine@~2.0.1 fetched in 1192ms
41 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasminewd2 3797ms (from cache)
42 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine 3799ms (from cache)
43 silly pacote range manifest for @types/jasminewd2@~2.0.3 fetched in 3802ms
44 silly pacote range manifest for @types/jasmine@~3.3.8 fetched in 3804ms
45 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine-html-reporter 1353ms (from cache)
46 silly pacote range manifest for karma-jasmine-html-reporter@^1.4.0 fetched in 1354ms
47 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-node 1327ms (from cache)
48 silly pacote range manifest for ts-node@~7.0.0 fetched in 1334ms
49 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor 1369ms (from cache)
50 silly pacote range manifest for protractor@~5.4.0 fetched in 1371ms
51 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint 911ms (from cache)
52 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tslint@~5.15.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^5.3.30","chai":"^3.5'
53 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations 2574ms (from cache)
54 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/animations@~8.2.14 fetched in 2578ms
55 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon 2566ms (from cache)
56 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler 2562ms (from cache)
57 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/common@~8.2.14 fetched in 2573ms
58 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/compiler@~8.2.14 fetched in 2567ms
59 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 2569ms (from cache)
60 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/core@~8.2.14 fetched in 2573ms
61 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 3967ms (from cache)
62 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 3140ms (from cache)
63 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/forms@~8.2.14 fetched in 3978ms
64 silly pacote range manifest for rxjs@~6.4.0 fetched in 3149ms
65 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 3543ms (from cache)
66 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~8.2.14 fetched in 3546ms
67 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter 3546ms (from cache)
68 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/router@~8.2.14 fetched in 3552ms
69 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 3597ms (from cache)
70 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/platform-browser@~8.2.14 fetched in 3600ms
71 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib 3261ms (from cache)
72 silly pacote range manifest for tslib@^1.10.0 fetched in 3263ms
73 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js 3279ms (from cache)
74 silly pacote range manifest for zone.js@~0.9.1 fetched in 3283ms
75 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2farchitect 3297ms (from cache)
76 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/architect@0.803.23 fetched in 3301ms
77 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fcore 3275ms (from cache)
78 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/core@8.3.23 fetched in 3279ms
79 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@schematics%2fupdate 4058ms (from cache)
80 silly pacote version manifest for @schematics/update@0.803.23 fetched in 4060ms
81 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics 4083ms (from cache)
82 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/schematics@8.3.23 fetched in 4086ms
83 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@schematics%2fangular 4096ms (from cache)
84 silly pacote version manifest for @schematics/angular@8.3.23 fetched in 4099ms
85 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@yarnpkg%2flockfile 5714ms (from cache)
86 silly pacote version manifest for @yarnpkg/lockfile@1.1.0 fetched in 5716ms
87 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-package-arg 5439ms (from cache)
88 silly pacote version manifest for npm-package-arg@6.1.0 fetched in 5441ms
89 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer 5457ms (from cache)
90 silly pacote version manifest for inquirer@6.5.1 fetched in 5459ms
91 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 5513ms (from cache)
92 silly pacote range manifest for debug@^4.1.1 fetched in 5515ms
93 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ini 5519ms (from cache)
94 silly pacote version manifest for ini@1.3.5 fetched in 5521ms
95 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-colors 7368ms (from cache)
96 silly pacote version manifest for ansi-colors@4.1.1 fetched in 7369ms
97 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-pick-manifest 3976ms (from cache)
98 silly pacote version manifest for npm-pick-manifest@3.0.2 fetched in 3979ms
99 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/open 3989ms (from cache)
100 silly pacote version manifest for open@6.4.0 fetched in 3991ms
101 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pacote 3992ms (from cache)
102 silly pacote version manifest for pacote@9.5.5 fetched in 3995ms
103 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-tree 2540ms (from cache)
104 silly pacote version manifest for read-package-tree@5.3.1 fetched in 2541ms
105 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 1184ms (from cache)
106 silly pacote version manifest for rimraf@3.0.0 fetched in 1186ms
107 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 1182ms (from cache)
108 silly pacote version manifest for semver@6.3.0 fetched in 1183ms
109 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/symbol-observable 1181ms (from cache)
110 silly pacote version manifest for symbol-observable@1.2.0 fetched in 1181ms
111 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/universal-analytics 1160ms (from cache)
112 silly pacote range manifest for universal-analytics@^0.4.20 fetched in 1161ms
113 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid 1117ms (from cache)
114 silly pacote range manifest for uuid@^3.3.2 fetched in 1118ms
115 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-webpack 534ms (from cache)
116 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.803.23 fetched in 537ms
117 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-optimizer 562ms (from cache)
118 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.803.23 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...1XEOnhupLz3iqkeQEufOD'
119 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcore 532ms (from cache)
120 silly pacote version manifest for @babel/core@7.7.5 fetched in 533ms
121 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fpreset-env 3421ms (from cache)
122 silly pacote version manifest for @babel/preset-env@7.7.6 fetched in 3428ms
123 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ngtools%2fwebpack 3371ms (from cache)
124 silly pacote version manifest for @ngtools/webpack@8.3.23 fetched in 3374ms
125 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv 3391ms (from cache)
126 silly pacote version manifest for ajv@6.10.2 fetched in 3394ms
127 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/caniuse-lite 3325ms (from cache)
128 silly pacote version manifest for caniuse-lite@1.0.30001019 fetched in 3330ms
129 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserslist 3449ms (from cache)
130 silly pacote version manifest for browserslist@4.8.3 fetched in 3452ms
131 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer 3475ms (from cache)
132 silly pacote version manifest for autoprefixer@9.6.1 fetched in 3479ms
133 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/circular-dependency-plugin 3431ms (from cache)
134 silly pacote version manifest for circular-dependency-plugin@5.2.0 fetched in 3434ms
135 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cacache 3555ms (from cache)
136 silly pacote version manifest for cacache@12.0.2 fetched in 3558ms
137 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css 3481ms (from cache)
138 silly pacote version manifest for clean-css@4.2.1 fetched in 3483ms
139 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js 3651ms (from cache)
140 silly pacote version manifest for core-js@3.2.1 fetched in 3653ms
141 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/find-cache-dir 3581ms (from cache)
142 silly pacote version manifest for find-cache-dir@3.0.0 fetched in 3583ms
143 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coverage-istanbul-loader 3855ms (from cache)
144 silly pacote version manifest for coverage-istanbul-loader@2.0.3 fetched in 3857ms
145 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/file-loader 3640ms (from cache)
146 silly pacote version manifest for file-loader@4.2.0 fetched in 3642ms
147 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob 3600ms (from cache)
148 silly pacote version manifest for glob@7.1.4 fetched in 3602ms
149 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/copy-webpack-plugin 3728ms (from cache)
150 silly pacote version manifest for copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.1 fetched in 3729ms
151 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jest-worker 3553ms (from cache)
152 silly pacote version manifest for jest-worker@24.9.0 fetched in 3554ms
153 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-source-map-support 3517ms (from cache)
154 silly pacote version manifest for karma-source-map-support@1.4.0 fetched in 3519ms
155 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/less 4513ms (from cache)
156 silly pacote version manifest for less@3.9.0 fetched in 4515ms
157 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mini-css-extract-plugin 2125ms (from cache)
158 silly pacote version manifest for mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.0 fetched in 2127ms
159 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/license-webpack-plugin 2153ms (from cache)
160 silly pacote version manifest for license-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 fetched in 2157ms
161 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils 2150ms (from cache)
162 silly pacote version manifest for loader-utils@1.2.3 fetched in 2151ms
163 silly pacote version manifest for rxjs@6.4.0 fetched in 1ms
164 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/less-loader 2199ms (from cache)
165 silly pacote version manifest for less-loader@5.0.0 fetched in 2200ms
166 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parse5 2161ms (from cache)
167 silly pacote version manifest for parse5@4.0.0 fetched in 2162ms
168 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch 2190ms (from cache)
169 silly pacote version manifest for minimatch@3.0.4 fetched in 2191ms
170 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss 2183ms (from cache)
171 silly pacote version manifest for postcss@7.0.17 fetched in 2186ms
172 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-import 2199ms (from cache)
173 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-import@12.0.1 fetched in 2200ms
174 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-loader 3607ms (from cache)
175 silly pacote version manifest for postcss-loader@3.0.0 fetched in 3609ms
176 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-loader 3680ms (from cache)
177 silly pacote version manifest for raw-loader@3.1.0 fetched in 3683ms
178 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/regenerator-runtime 3675ms (from cache)
179 silly pacote version manifest for regenerator-runtime@0.13.3 fetched in 3678ms
180 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass 3675ms (from cache)
181 silly pacote version manifest for sass@1.22.9 fetched in 3678ms
182 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map 3653ms (from cache)
183 silly pacote version manifest for source-map@0.7.3 fetched in 3655ms
184 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass-loader 3669ms (from cache)
185 silly pacote version manifest for sass-loader@7.2.0 fetched in 3672ms
186 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support 3651ms (from cache)
187 silly pacote version manifest for source-map-support@0.5.13 fetched in 3655ms
188 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-loader 3649ms (from cache)
189 silly pacote version manifest for source-map-loader@0.2.4 fetched in 3651ms
190 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/speed-measure-webpack-plugin 3648ms (from cache)
191 silly pacote version manifest for speed-measure-webpack-plugin@1.3.1 fetched in 3649ms
192 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/style-loader 5273ms (from cache)
193 silly pacote version manifest for style-loader@1.0.0 fetched in 5274ms
194 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus-loader 4148ms (from cache)
195 silly pacote version manifest for stylus-loader@3.0.2 fetched in 4151ms
196 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus 4277ms (from cache)
197 silly pacote version manifest for stylus@0.54.5 fetched in 4285ms
198 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tree-kill 4308ms (from cache)
199 silly pacote version manifest for tree-kill@1.2.2 fetched in 4310ms
200 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/terser 4358ms (from cache)
201 silly pacote version manifest for terser@4.3.9 fetched in 4363ms
202 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/terser-webpack-plugin 4412ms (from cache)
203 silly pacote version manifest for terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.3 fetched in 4415ms
204 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-middleware 4412ms (from cache)
205 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 fetched in 4415ms
206 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server 4415ms (from cache)
207 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-dev-server@3.9.0 fetched in 4419ms
208 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 4488ms (from cache)
209 silly pacote version manifest for webpack@4.39.2 fetched in 4501ms
210 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-merge 1170ms (from cache)
211 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-merge@4.2.1 fetched in 1171ms
212 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata 905ms (from cache)
213 silly pacote range manifest for reflect-metadata@^0.1.2 fetched in 907ms
214 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/worker-plugin 977ms (from cache)
215 silly pacote version manifest for worker-plugin@3.2.0 fetched in 978ms
216 silly pacote range manifest for source-map@^0.6.1 fetched in 2ms
217 silly pacote range manifest for tslib@^1.9.0 fetched in 1ms
218 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist 862ms (from cache)
219 silly pacote range manifest for minimist@^1.2.0 fetched in 863ms
220 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-sources 1198ms (from cache)
221 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-sources@1.4.3 fetched in 1200ms
222 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canonical-path 896ms (from cache)
223 silly pacote version manifest for canonical-path@1.0.0 fetched in 897ms
224 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-subresource-integrity 1094ms (from cache)
225 silly pacote version manifest for webpack-subresource-integrity@1.1.0-rc.6 fetched in 1096ms
226 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar 897ms (from cache)
227 silly pacote range manifest for chokidar@^2.1.1 fetched in 899ms
228 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/convert-source-map 855ms (from cache)
229 silly pacote range manifest for convert-source-map@^1.5.1 fetched in 857ms
230 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/magic-string 1202ms (from cache)
231 silly pacote range manifest for magic-string@^0.25.0 fetched in 1204ms
232 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dependency-graph 1223ms (from cache)
233 silly pacote range manifest for dependency-graph@^0.7.2 fetched in 1225ms
234 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs 1211ms (from cache)
235 silly pacote version manifest for yargs@13.1.0 fetched in 1214ms
236 silly pacote range manifest for source-map@^0.5.7 fetched in 2ms
237 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors 1212ms (from cache)
238 silly pacote version manifest for colors@1.1.2 fetched in 1213ms
239 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/app-root-path 1193ms (from cache)
240 silly pacote range manifest for app-root-path@^2.2.1 fetched in 1194ms
241 silly pacote range manifest for minimatch@^3.0.4 fetched in 1ms
242 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/axobject-query 1195ms (from cache)
243 silly pacote version manifest for axobject-query@2.0.2 fetched in 1196ms
244 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aria-query 1241ms (from cache)
245 silly pacote range manifest for aria-query@^3.0.0 fetched in 1243ms
246 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-selector-tokenizer 1222ms (from cache)
247 silly pacote range manifest for css-selector-tokenizer@^0.7.1 fetched in 1223ms
248 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssauron 1276ms (from cache)
249 silly pacote range manifest for cssauron@^1.4.0 fetched in 1280ms
250 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/damerau-levenshtein 1858ms (from cache)
251 silly pacote range manifest for damerau-levenshtein@^1.0.4 fetched in 1859ms
252 silly pacote range manifest for chokidar@^2.0.3 fetched in 2ms
253 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver-dsl 1849ms (from cache)
254 silly pacote range manifest for colors@^1.1.0 fetched in 2ms
255 silly pacote range manifest for semver-dsl@^1.0.1 fetched in 1852ms
256 silly pacote range manifest for core-js@^2.2.0 fetched in 4ms
257 warn deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
258 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird 1772ms (from cache)
259 silly pacote range manifest for bluebird@^3.3.0 fetched in 1775ms
260 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/braces 1808ms (from cache)
261 silly pacote range manifest for braces@^2.3.2 fetched in 1811ms
262 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul-api 1971ms (from cache)
```

Comment: Its a Proxy Error. Check your Ip by "ping registry.npmjs.org"

Comment: Try this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553473/9752928)

Comment: same error for me as well :(

Answer (score 2):

1. first delete registry using: npm config delete registry
2. clear cache: npm cache clear --force
3. now run your command: ng new myApp

Hope it helps. it should work because I was facing same issue and it took me 2 days to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue related to NPM not angular, You may want to check your NPM proxy settings and perhaps remove it.

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: Dear Sanjeetharan, I tried the above command you mention but still I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm  cache clear --force` and then re-running `npm install`

Comment: Hi stedice thank you for your response. I tried npm clear cache --force   even I'm getting the same error.