# Atom platformio-ide-terminal installation failed with message:

Tags: atom-editor

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-FwSR4ZRPW0KlivAwPXSK0RXh9KEP0ApBbO7MqHT1z6UxK/NbX6+JcrShhODByECQATvi9j90xwr0VIs9o/CAZA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-FwSR4ZRPW0KlivAwPXSK0RXh9KEP0ApBbO7MqHT1z6UxK/NbX6+JcrShhODByECQATvi9j90xwr0VIs9o/CAZA== but got sha512-+7zo2YZURDS4sJVSSCmvNKYFPfsWPfN2eHciUQfFGhA3zDNX8UrSbVYUkmTtBbXPsv8hHN16PngPRv5a+LdqPQ==. (15964 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-space-pen-views: Integrity verification failed for sha512-FwSR4ZRPW0KlivAwPXSK0RXh9KEP0ApBbO7MqHT1z6UxK/NbX6+JcrShhODByECQATvi9j90xwr0VIs9o/CAZA== (C:\Users\Pranshu\.atom\.apm\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\17\04\91e1944f5b42a58af0303d748ad115e1f4a10fd00a416ceecca874f5cfa5312bf35b5faf8972b4a184e0c1c84090013be2f63f74c70af4548b3da3f08064)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pranshu\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-04-22T18_28_14_921Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy or VPN or a public connection with a captive portal?

Comment: Could you post the content of the log file? 'C:\Users\Pranshu\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-04-22T18_28_14_921Z-debug.log'

Comment: Related? [npm - using stale package data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45553401/4518341), [Can't install linter-eslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/1248) - I'm not familiar with npm myself so not sure how much these help

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need more information. Edit your question and add your location, and whether you're using a proxy or VPN. Don't add "edit" or "update" type tags as we can see what changed. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by deleting apm cache folder files:

```
# cd ~/.atom/.apm/_cacache/

# rm -Rf *
```